# Unable to write to a plist URL

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I have a pNameDict as:

```
var pNameDict:[String: AnyObject] = [:]
```

This dict is populated with data from a plist file and subsequently updated with user input.

When I try to write back the data, it does not work. I do see the pNameDict getting updated but the write fails.

```
func saveNames() {
    var pListURL: URL?
    var pListData: NSData?
    do {
        pListURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Names", withExtension: "plist", subdirectory: "")
        pListData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: pNameDict, format: .binary, options: 0) as NSData
        pListData?.write(to: pListURL!, atomically: false)
    } catch {
        print("Could not write data to plist")
    }
}
```

Comment: An app's bundle is read-only.

Comment: Thank you maddy! I was able to see the error which was "Permission Denied". But seeing few old posting on this topic, I was thinking there is something I may be doing wrong. Thanks for confirming.